# VS code doesn't lint my code, but the insider build does

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

### Problem:

After I updated VS Code to version 1.21.0 the Pylint Linter does not work.

I receive no linting errors in the problems tab inside of VS Code.

I deliberately made some errors to confirm this behaviour.

## Expected result:

When I make a style error I expect my linter to notify my like it did before.

## What have I tried?

#### Pylint

- I checked that pylint is installed.

  - I updated pylint using PIP while I was at it.
- I tried enabling another Linter (Pep8), but these also didn't give me the expected result

#### VS Code

- I checked my VS Code settings that linting is enabled.
- I have installed VS code insiders build.

  - Here there was no problem, my code was being linted.
  - I copied my settings from VS code to the insider build, to double check.
  - Since it works on the insiders build, it can't be a PATH issue.

    - previously it also worked on the normal build, so a PATH issue is out of the question i think.
  - I prefer to use the stable release.
- I tried the command: "Python: Enable Linting".

  - The following error message appeared in VS Code:

    - [VS Code error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swlXc.png)
  - Other commands associated with the Python extension result in a similar error:

    - [Other error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P4gc.png)
  - These commands do not result in an error on the insider build.

#### General

- I have removed the Python extension and reinstalled it.
- I have removed VS Code and reinstalled it.

  - Both resulted in the same problem as before .

#### Search

- I searched GitHub issues.
- I searched Stack overflow questions.
- I searched the official documentation.

  - Both VS code documentation as Pylint documentation as well as the Python extension documentation.

## Question

- Did I miss anything in my testing that could solve this issue?
- Is this a bug that I should report?

  - If so, is this a VS Code bug? a Python extension bug?

My VS Code USER SETTINGS:

```
{
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
"[python]": {

},
"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
"explorer.sortOrder": "type",
"editor.rulers": [
    79
],
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
}
```

Comment: Looking at the errors you have received, its most likely your installation of the extension is corrupted.
Please uninstall the extension and reinstall it, if that fails, go into the extensions directory and delete the python extension folder (use the command `Open Extensions Folder` from the command palette).

Comment: This worked. I removed for a third time, and now I have linting working. How do I give you credits for this answer?

Comment: Nearly the same problem here.  In V1.21 all Python debugging stopped working.  Uninstall / reinstall didn't help.  But deleting the folder (Open Extensions Folder) as above and deleting, then re-installing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the errors you have received, your installation of the extension is corrupted. Please uninstall the extension and reinstall it, if that fails, go into the extensions directory and delete the python extension folder (use the command Open Extensions Folder from the command palette).

That should fix the problem.